# p value of 1 for Mann-Whitney U - artifact?

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

I'm using the `rstatix` library in R 3.6.3 through RStudio 1.2.5042 and am getting the impossible p-value of 1 when running a two-sample Wilcoxon aka Mann-Whitney U Test.

My first instinct says this is a floating point precision issue and the actual value is something like 0.999999 but I came here to confirm before an undisclosed federal research agency gets up my ass about it.

Here's my code:

```
wilcox_test(data,
            DV ~ Group,
            paired = F,
            exact = T, 
            alternative = "two.sided",
            conf.level = 0.95,
            detailed = T)
```

[Link to .csv formatted data](https://filebin.net/p5vc03lri8lan2om)

Data has been anonymized of course. This link expires in 1 week.

Cross-posting for consistency:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467572/p-value-of-1-for-mann-whitney-u-artifact-of-r

Comment: P-value = 1 must mean the test statistic is the least possibly unusual or most possibly typical value. What is that "most boring" value for the test statistic? Can you verify that the test statistic has been computed correctly for your data? (dput(wilcox_test(...)) should show all the details.) Also, your data file is pretty small; instead of posting an ephemeral link, maybe just paste the data into your problem statement. Finally, this is more off topic for stats.stackexchange.com since it's more conceptual. PS. tnx for the laugh.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier will do!

Comment: Appreciate the cross-post link, but please avoid doing that: it wastes time and effort. Instead, guess the best venue and go with it.  If you get no interest in a reasonable amount of time, or a consensus that you guessed wrong, then you can re-post/cross-post to the other place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of digging finds that `rstatix::wilcox_test()` is suppressing warnings about ties being incompatible with exactness in its implementation.  If you run plain old `stats::wilcox.test()` (which `rstatix` is calling eventually anyway), this happens:

```
w <- wilcox.test(DV~Group,data=dat)
```

> Warning message:
>   In wilcox.test.default(x = c(5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L,  :
>     cannot compute exact p-value with ties

You can see [here](https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/blob/8044e6c4085ac893b2b5d09eb3a0838c13657785/R/utilities_two_sample_test.R#L102-L107) that `rstatix` is suppressing this warning.

Just to double-check, I worked through the guts of `wilcox.test`: the formula for the Z-statistic for the approximate test is

```
STATISTIC-n.x*n.y/2-CORRECTION
```

(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test): doesn't mention the continuity correction though).

In this case the W-statistic is 209.5, `n.x*n.y/2` is 209, and the continuity correction is 0.5 - so you do get a Z-statistic of exactly zero, so that `pnorm(z)` is 0.5 and the two-tailed test statistic is *exactly* 1.

If you instead want to deal with the ties exactly:

```
coin::wilcox_test(DV~factor(Group), data=dat, distribution="exact")
##  Exact Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
## data:  DV by factor(Group) (Control, Treatment)
## Z = 0.013327, p-value = 0.9954
## alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

Comment: This is a great explanation! So is the moral here that when you have ties you should use the coin::wilcox_test instead?

Comment: if you don't want to make asymptotic approximations, yes. (I claim that here the difference between p=0.9954 and p=1 is unlikely to be *practically* important ...).  The other moral is that suppressing warning messages is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

P-values of 1 are not impossible, as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161545/what-does-a-p-value-of-exactly-1-0000-mean) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_a_p-value_be_10). Also note that in your case the exact p-value cannot be computed because you have ties. The function you use does not give this information but the `wilcox.test() function`  from the stats package gives a warning.

```
wilcox.test(test_data$DV ~ test_data$Group)

#>Warning message:
#>In wilcox.test.default(x = c(5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1,  :
#>  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Comment: I also saw those posts but they did not clear up my question. The first link implicates bonferonni correction but i didn't do any p-value adjustments because there weren't multiple comparisons. As well, my data is not discrete, it's continuous. They also mention that I might need a "two.sided" test which I was already using. So that post further suggests that this is a precision issue. I set exact p-value to FALSE and there was no difference.

Comment: Ignore the part where I say this is continuous data, it is indeed ordinal data!

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that the first part of my answer overlaps exactly with yours (although I did provide a little more detail ...)

Comment: No worries, your answer is indeed more detailed contains additional insights.